# Unable to access to my json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Working in a jquery request in JSON but I have some problem to access to my data.

My request is :

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
    $("#client").change( function() {                        
        $.ajax({ 
           type: "GET",
           url: "jsonContacts.php", 
           data: "q="+$("#client").val(),
           success: function(data){
                document.form.contactClient.options.length=0;
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    document.form.contactClient.options[i]=new Option(data[i].prenom, data[i].id, false, false);
                }       
                document.form.contactClient.options[i]=new Option("End", i, false, false);

           }
        });
    });
});
```

When I put

```
       alert(data[1].prenom);
```

It gives me undefined :/

Here an example of my json :

```
[{"id":"1","prenom":"Maxime","nom":"Xnate"},{"id":"3","prenom":"Test_prenom","nom":"Test_nom"}]
```

My request displays two empty options and one option "End", so it goes well across array but can't get any data.

So do you have any idea about the access of the data ?

Thanks

EDIT :

My json encoding

```
$json = array();

while($contact = $requeteContact->fetch()) {
    array_push($json, array("id" => $contact['idContact'],
                            "prenom" => $contact['CTC_Prenom'],
                            "nom" => $contact['CTC_Nom']));
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Working :

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
    $("#client").blur( function() {                        
        $.ajax({ 
           type: "GET",
           url: "jsonContacts.php", 
           data: "q="+$("#client").val(),
           success: function(data){
                document.form.contactClient.options.length=0;
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    document.form.contactClient.options[i]=new Option(data[i].prenom + " " + data[i].nom, data[i].id, false, false);
                }       
                document.form.contactClient.options[i]=new Option("End", i, false, false);

           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is returned in the above said format?

Comment: Use `dataType: "json"` or "jsonp" for cross-origin requests to get a true JSON response.

Comment: well that's what it gives me when i go manually to jsonContacts.php?q=Actemium at least

Comment: My request doesn't work anymore when I add dataType: "json", to parameters :/

Comment: Print the complete "data" array and check what are you getting back from the server.

Comment: Are you sure you get result in JSON format? You can first try to parse data with JSON.parse(data) if server does not return JSON but only plain text (which is JSON formated)... So var parsedData = JSON.parse(data) and then parsedData[i].prenom in for loop.

Comment: My array looks totally empty. I tried with parsing JSON but it doesn't even go in the loop anymore.
I add my json encoding in first post

Comment: Did you also change loop condtition from data.length to parsedData.length (or whatever name you used)? Please add alert(data) and tell us what you get.

Comment: yes i changed it also.
alert(data); gives me []

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Don't have access to fiddle here, compatibility problem :/
I changed my event 'change' to 'blur' and it works that way, so weird. Any idea to make it work with change event ?

Comment: Can you hardcode the  data: `"q="+$("#client").val(),` than get value of  #client and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is probably just returned as a string. You can solve this in several ways:

1) use getJSON.

```
$.getJSON('http://..',{q:$("#client").val()},function(result){
})
```

2) Parse the string as JSON

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

3) Set the dataType to 'json'. If you do this, you will have to sett the content-type on the server side to 'application/json'. In PHP this would look like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: On getJSON, when I type alert(data);, it just displays me an empty window. already tried parsing, didn't work.
Tried also with the header, didn't work neither :/

Comment: That's because getJSON returns an object. Try alert(JSON.stringify(data));, or alert(data[0].id);

Comment: I've partially resolved the problem by changing my event from 'change' to 'blur' but it would be nice if it worked with change

Comment: I'm going to assume you do this inside the success-function, so there is no asynchronous issues. Try looping through it like this:

$.each(data,function(key,val) {
   console.log(key,val["prenom"]);
});

could you post an updated version of your code if this does not work?

Comment: If your server returns valid JSON, this should work just fine: http://pastebin.com/mZxHaSBV 

 Open the console to see the results.

Comment: Well, i never did any jquery before that, i'll stay on my simple version which works with blur, it in't that bad as event ! :p
Updated my first post to show you wich version works

Comment: But, i'm wondering, is it possible to have another ajax function on the same event ? because twice of my input depends of this client value

Comment: Sure, just add it to the selector, like so: $("#input1, #input2").blur(function() {})